# Linq to XML, collection is empty!

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I have an XDocument in the format:

```
<S xmlns="http://server.com/DAAPI">
   <TIMESTAMP>2010-08-17 10:14:31.937</TIMESTAMP>
   <REP_GROUP>
     <GROUP></GROUP>
     <NAME></NAME>
     <LOCAL_NAME></LOCAL_NAME>
                 ........
   </REP_GROUP>
   <REP_GROUP>
    <GROUP>AMZ </GROUP>
    ..............
```

Why when I do

```
XNamespace ns = "http://server.com/DAAPI";
xDocument.Elements( ns + "REP_GROUP" ).Count()
```

do i get a count of zero?

Comment: Please demonstrate why getting a count of 0 is incorrect.  Maybe there are 0 elements that match your string?  A start would be to post the XML you are querying.

Comment: Apologies, you had added the XML, but just not marked corectly as code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your variable name is accurate, it's because your *document* only has one element - `<S>`, the root element. Try this:

```
int count = xDocument.Root.Elements(ns + "REP_GROUP" ).Count();
```